# how to capture onchange field value in record edit from LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

I am trying to clone a record by using recordeditform in LWC. On quick action click i am populating record fields.

If a user is changing value on Text__c field and keeping name field as it is, how to get the changed field value and not changed field value in **this.oppRecord** variable and send it to apex.

currently even if i change value, i am getting the old value.

HTML

```
 <lightning-record-edit-form layout-type="Full" record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Opportunity" onload={handleonLoad}>
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                        <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small" size="6">
                                <lightning-input-field data-field="Name" field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small" size="6">
                                <lightning-input-field data-field="Text__c" field-name="Text__c" onchange={handlechange}></lightning-input-field>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                        </lightning-record-edit-form>
                                <footer>
                <div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer attach-to-bottom">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={insertCloneOpp}>
                        </lightning-button>
                </div>
        </footer>
```

JS

```
handleonLoad(event) {
        if (!this.loadedForm) {
            let fields = Object.values(event.detail.records)[0].fields;
            const recordId = Object.keys(event.detail.records)[0];
            console.log(this.recordTypeName);
            this.oppRecord = {
                Id: recordId,
                ...Object.keys(fields)
                    .filter((field) => !!this.template.querySelector(`[data-field=${field}]`))
                    .reduce((total, field) => {
                        total[field] = fields[field].value;
                        return total;
                    }, {})
            };
            this.loadedForm = true;

        }
    }
    handlechange(event) {
    cosole.log(event.target.value);
   }
    insertCloneOpp() {
        console.log('Opp', JSON.stringify(this.oppRecord));
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to create another opportunity record with the changed value from the edit form if the name is not changed, did I understand correctly?

Comment: i m basically cloning opportunity record with some changed and some not changed values. Means user can change some value and keep some value as it is

Comment: i added onchange event in Text__c field. i am getting the changed value, but how to append this change to this.opprecord as this will be send to apex.

Comment: Try event.detail.value instead event.target.value